# Migrate VS2015 to VS2019 Reference missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019, design-view, assembly-reference-path, resolveassemblyreference

I need to upgrade the VS2015 version to VS2019. I have VS2015 and VS2019 installed on my PC.
When I build my project using VS2015, everything run fine and able to view the GUI.
The same project when I open as VS2019, the reference was missing. But it can still build successfully without error.

Solution tried not working:

1.) Open and close VS2019. Reopen it still same.

2.) Reinstall VS2019

3.) Add reference, but the reference page is blank.

VS2019 Add reference but empty choice

[image]

My goal is able to view the GUI in VS2019.
Anyone have solution for this? Appreciate if can help me.

VS2015 Reference Correct Behavior

[image]

VS2019 Reference Missing

[image]

Design View not able to use due to missing reference

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: make sure the .net/C++ workloads and C++/CLI support are installed

Comment: Yap, I have already done that previously. This is because I could create a separate WinForm from scratch using VS2019. I also checked on Tools, that has already been installed.